# Chrome support for MathML in most recent beta

Tags: google-chrome, mathml

According to [this](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/a-web-developers-guide-to-latest-chrome.html) annoucment and thanks to Dave Barton, chrome should be supporting MathML in the most recent beta version. I am running Version 24.0.1312.40 beta, but MathML seems to be turned off, since I can't render the examples on [this](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/) page. How do I turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dave Barton, Google temporarily deactivated MathML support in Chrome 24 again. It should be turned back on again soon and make it into the final release.

Comment: Right. You can also use Chrome Canary for trying out upcoming features like this - it has the latest MathML, turned on now. See http://paulirish.com/2012/chrome-canary-for-developers/ and you may also like http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430#c22

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 24 stable was released last week with MathML turned *on*.

http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/stable-channel-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MathJax contextual menu to set the Math Renderer to MathML (in the Math Settings submenu).  You may get a warning that MathML isn't supported, but can go ahead and set it anyway.

While the WebKit implementation of MathML has improved greatly do to Dave Barton's efforts, you may still find that it is not adequate for the equations you need to view, so be aware that not everything will display properly in native MathML mode in Chrome.

Comment: I did that, and the output I get is the same as with chrome 23 (not even the fractions, radicals or superscripts work.) Safari with it's implementation of webkit does all of that beautifully, which caused me to conclude that somehow I had to turn on the experimental MathML support inside chrome, maybe with a command-line flag or something simmilar.